# electron-packager is packing with old version files

Tags: electron, electron-packager

I have an Electron+Angular application.

When I build the Angular app, it goes to **dist** folder, ok. And when I use **electron-packager** and **electron-builder**, it put the files inside **dist** too.

For the first version it's ok. The problem is when I'm building a second version. It packs the old version files that is inside **dist** folder. And the result is a large .exe file.

These is the commands I'm using to pack and publish my app:

```
electron-packager . --overwrite --asar=true --platform=win32 --ignore=ˆ/tmp

electron-builder --publish always
```

How can I prevent the old version files to be packed in new versions? Should I remove them every time I build a new version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved my problem

I'm new with Electron, so I though that run electron-packager was necessary before publish new versions.

You only need to run:

```
electron-builder --publish always
```

**electron-packager** packs everything inside **dist** folder and creates a new folder outside dist.

**electron-builder** create necessary files to publish but ignores the old version files that was created for it. But if you have that new folder created by **electron-packager** it'll be published too and your .exe will be very large.